# Closing a web page after submit

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to close a document after someone has updated it.

I tried the following javascript in the submit button:

document.forms[0].submit();
window.close()

But the web-query-save agent doesn't fire then.  But if I comment out the 'close', the WQS agent executes as expected but then I have the dreaded "Form Processed" page.  I supposed I could but a nice page up but I'd like to just close the page.  Any thoughts?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your WebQuerySave Agent you can print a message to output some javascript.

```
Print |<script type="text\javascript">| 
Print |window.close();| 
Print |</script>|
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 9 years old, but this solution didn't work for me.

Instead, I end my `webquerysave` agent with a Print statement back to the same document:

```
Print "[" + webDbPath + "/0/" + currdoc.Universalid + "?EditDocument&saveSuccess=true]"
```

I can then check for the `saveSuccess` in the URL on the onload and if found, close the window with: `window.open('','_self').close();`